# Django Rest Framework specify that email must be unique

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here's a serializer for registering a user.

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])

        return user
```

Here's the api view:

```
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        return Response({
        "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
        # "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })
```

On the api view, if I try to pass in a name that is exactly the same as an existing name, it will say that it already exists. However, I can still make the emails the same which I don't want. Is there a way to get it so that I can also tell DRF that I would like the email to have to be unique as well?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [`UniqueValidator`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#uniquevalidator)?

Comment: How can I apply that to the current serializer I have

Comment: Please take a look at my answer for implementing it

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 options:

1. Enforcing the unique criterion on the serializer level:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )  # recommend using `get_user_model`

    class Meta:
        model = User  # recommend using `get_user_model`
        ...

    ...
```

2. Using a custom User model that enforces the unique criterion on the model level. More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

**Note:** The 2nd option also requires making changes to the settings and potentially other areas of the code if you reference the `User` model directly in your other models. If you are directly using `User` in other areas of your code, please take a look at using [`get_user_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model).

Comment: How do I specify the email as a field in the first option

Comment: You still keep `fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password')` in your `Meta` block so that the serializer knows its referring to the model's field.

Comment: I can still send the same email if I just add that code.

Comment: Did you add `email = serializers.EmailField(validators=UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])` before the `Meta` block? Basically, keeping everything the same in your serializer, just add this line before your `Meta` block.

Comment: Here is what I have class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    ) 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `ModelSerializer` I think you can achieve it by having emails as unique field in the model itself and the serializer will handle the validation part for you.